# Set JAVA_HOME path for Cordova

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I just installed Cordova and Ionic, and now I was trying to compile my first apk with this command:
ionic cordova build --release android

After a few seconds I get this error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOPax.png[image]

I downloaded and installed the updated JDK, but the same error continues to appear.
How do I change the JAVA_HOME path?
Thank you

Comment: It's a system environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you are still using 1.7 as it is showing img screenshot.
if you installed new version make sure you have uninstall old version (1.7).
you can download JDK 1.8 version [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

if you are using WINDOWS follow these steps to change JAVA_HOME path.
1) go to my computer properties.
2) click on Advanced system settings (A new window will be open).
3) click on Enviroment Variables Button.
4) in System variables panel. find JAVA_HOME variable and click on EDIT.

Comment: And don't forget to restart the console or terminal or powershell after after these steps.